# Validate number type inputs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, validation

I am having a quite complex problem dealing with jQuery validation on optional fields that have the `type="number"` specified. What happens is that the browser (Chrome in this case) allows the user to enter normal letters in the field, with the idea of intercepting the submitting of the form and anyway, when the field value is queried, it will return an empty string.

Before going forward, I must say that this is kind-of in line with the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#number-state-%28type=number%29), that states:

> User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty string that is not a valid floating-point number.

and later on:

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then **set it to the empty string** instead.

Here lies the problem: if I enter letters in an optional number input fields (and Chrome allows that), the jQuery validation gets an empty string value which validates correctly since the field is optional. Moreover, I get the emtpy string server side which is ok since the field is nullable in the DB and happily gets saved.

For the time being, the only workaround that I can think of is this:

```
$('input[type="number"]').keypress(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode < 48 || evt.keyCode > 57)
        evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Problem is that the above does not work, for example, if the user copy-pastes some wrong input there. Now, I realize that if the user is so determined to enter dumb data he can only face the consequences and have that field nullified, but trying to be a good developer I was wondering if there is a way of obtaining the value entered without using the workarond above (and also without writing another workaround for copypaste).

Comment: My chrome is not letting me submit non-number in a number input.  See http://jsfiddle.net/wr5KU/

Comment: @DMoses, yes that is what it should do, but on using jquery validate and unobtrusive stuff apparently the submit event of the form is handled by jQuery so Chrome has no power on it...

Comment: Can't reproduce, am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/qqdBp/

Comment: As I said, it is probably the mix between Microsoft unobtrusive validation libraries and jquery validate(). The site I am writing is not public facing so I can't show you I'm afraid, but that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the Microsoft validation library in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jquery.alphanum](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum) is a plugin I wrote to prevent invalid text being entered in the first place. It handles copy-paste very well and is Cross-Browser Compatible.

```
$('input[type="number"]').numeric();
```

The plugin traps the paste event and filters the text before it becomes visible to the user.

Comment: It is a nice plugin, but it works on the same principle as @rahul's answer, meaning that it will blank out the field on blur... the trim functions will just do nothing since the values are already empty.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Chrome seems to work quite differently from Firefox in this situation. Let me see if I can write a fix for jquery.alphanum

Comment: Holy crap, I just put together a few unit tests to see how copy paste works in different browsers. I wrote 5 tests and ran them in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera. To my horror, no two browsers worked the same way. They were all completely different. I guess the days of Cross-Browser bugs are far from over. I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: Hi Tallmaris. I just published a fix for to [jquery.alphanum](http://plugins.jquery.com/alphanum/) that catches the paste event and filters the text before it becomes visible to the user. It works in browsers like Chrome that support the paste event. It's logged as  [issue #8](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum/issues/8) Hope it helps

Comment: I ended up using this plugin and it works better than the `jquery.numeric` plugin (which does not work on copypaste into `number` fields). To be honest, it still is a workaround for something which should probably be clearer (in the specs) or handled better either by the browsers or jQuery. Until that time, this is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.focusout()`  event of jquery . http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

and then use `isNumeric` to check for valid number. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric

so something like this..

```
$('input[type="number"]').focusout(function (evt) {
   if(!$.isNumeric($(this).val())){
     $(this).val("");
   }
});
```

Comment: Nice one! This works, although `$(this).val()` will always return an empty string on non-numeric input anyway, so I could just check that the val is empty and set the box to empty. I am not yet accepting this answer since it still sounds more like a workaround than a real fix for getting the value out of that box.

Comment: Based on the above comment, this works as well: `$(this).val($(this).val());`... The inner `val()` returns an empty string if the input is wrong and it is then assigned to the textbox again. =) nice eh?

Comment: Well thats works out well too.. the key point is using `focusout` instead of keypress or up events

Answer (score 0):

You can check input.validity.badInput to see if the user has entered something that isn't a valid number. The browser shouldn't let the user submit the form if the entered data isn't valid (unless you use novalidate="").

You can't get to the actual data the user has entered, because you've said you just want a number, so the browser takes care of it. If you want access to the data, use type=text with a pattern="" or some such.